# How to use excel services REST api in Sharepoint Hosted App

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel-services, rest

I need to call excel service rest api as follows on the 'Summary' library in hostweb

```
"https://<sponline>/sites/dev/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/Summary/Group%20Summary%202014.xlsx/Model/Tables('Revenue_Jan')?$format=atom"
```

The call should be executed from a SharePoint hosted app using JavaScript. I'm getting 'access denied' error when using below code in SharePoint hosted app.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: hostweburl + "/_vti_bin/ExcelREST.aspx/Summary/Group%20Summary%202014.xlsx/model/Tables?$'format=html'",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (xhr, msg, e) {
            alert("error");
        }
    });
```

If someone can point out a JavaScript code sample on how to use excel service from SharePoint hosted app it will be very helpful.

Comment: Where you able to get this working? Please share the source code if you do. Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: The issue is almost certainly with not passing the right headers to authenticate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't continue investigating how to do this on SharePoint app. I finally used a normal SharePoint webpage with following JavaScript.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "../_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/GroupStatistics/Group%20Summary%202014.xlsx/model/Tables('" + tableName + "')?$format=json",
        method: "GET",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //work with data
        },
        error: function (data) {
           // error
        }
    });
```