# How can i find the Excel services URL for my file?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, excel, excel-services, api

I'm trying to access through the Excel Rest API an excel file "My Excel File.xlsx", but regardless how I what excel services URL I use, I either get 404 or file does not exist or is deleted.

This is what I've tried:

https://mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/teams/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/CustomerZ/NewDocuments/Archived Renewal Items/My Excel File.xlsx/Model/Tables?$format=json

I can access the file normally from the browser using the URL as below.

https://mysharepointsite.sharepoint.com/:x:/r/teams/CustomerZ/NewDocuments/Archived Renewal Items/My Excel File.xlsx?d=dfs54lkj983m8crklfd98u45mdlksf4a2&csf=1&e=TgifaX

What would be the correct excel services URL?

Note that the URL are decoded to make things easier to understand, the original URL-s I've tried were correctly encoded.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be on the “*Tables?$format=json*” part.

Here’s another similar [post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100622/how-to-use-excel-services-rest-api-in-sharepoint-hosted-app) for your reference, the marked answer is using URL formatted as:

```
/_vti_bin/ExcelRest.aspx/…/My Excel File.xlsx/model/Tables('" + tableName + "')?$format=json
```

Or maybe use [Microsoft graph api](https://blog.atwork.at/post/Access-files-in-OneDrive-or-SharePoint-with-Microsoft-Graph-and-the-Excel-API) to get access to Excel files.

Other references:

[Basic URI Structure and Path.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/basic-uri-structure-and-path)

[Excel REST API in SharePoint Online.](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2013/12/17/excel-rest-api-in-sharepoint-online/)